# grails respond error page with status from Url mapping file

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Can I respond error pages with status code from url mapping file.

Basically I have a DemoController with Action Index. And I have created URL Mapping for "/" -> demo/index.
So now index action of demo controller is accessible by two urls i.r. /demo/index and /.

Now I want that if anyone hit /demo/index should be respond a error page with status 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply excluding `/demo/index` from mapping like this:

```
static excludes = ['/demo/index']
```